# bug ng-change com checkbox cheked

Tags: angularjs

O bug é o seguinte, tenho 2 `checkboxes`, acionando o primeiro o outro é marcado automaticamente, o segundo `checkbox` possui a `tag ng-change` que chama uma função no `controller`, o problema é, quando aciono o segundo `checkbox` de primeira, a `ng-change` funciona e faz a `call` correta da função, se eu aciono o primeiro `checkbox` marcando automaticamente o segundo, quando desmarco o segundo, ele já não faz a chamada da função, ele buga o primeiro `click` no segundo `checkbox`,

consegui reproduzir o erro

```js
angular.module('ToDo', [])
.controller('ToDoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.change = function(){
      console.log("changed");
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='ToDo'>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular To-Do App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ToDoController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ck1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ck2" ng-change="change()" ng-checked="ck1"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Existem várias formas de resolver esse problema. Você realmente precisa que o model do primeiro checkbox tenha um nome diferente do segundo? Qual é a necessidade do `change`. Será que não seria melhor usar um `$scope.$watch` ao invés de uma função que é capturada pelo `ng-change`?

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que no seu caso seria melhor usar o `$watch` do que o `ng-change` para "acompanhar" as mudanças na variável.

Não sei qual é a necessidade de você usar duas variaveis com nomes diferentes, mas fiz uma solução baseada no código oferecido na pergunta.

Veja:

```js
angular.module('ToDo', [])
.controller('ToDoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('ck2', function(valor){
      if (valor == true) {
          console.log("changed");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='ToDo'>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular To-Do App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ToDoController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ck1" ng-change="ck2=ck1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ck2" ng-checked="ck1"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Usei o `ng-change` no primeiro `checkbox` para, quando o mesmo for alterado, alterar o valor da variável `ck2`.

Veja a documentação do [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Tem como usar o watch em vários inputs, pela class do CSS, por exemplo, é que na vdd vou fazer uma consulta, e para cada linha retornada vou criar 2 inputs, usando a mesma ideia, cada input checkado vai automaticamente checar o outro correspondente